# Puppet Does not load class in custom module

Tags: module, puppet

A beginner environment with Puppet(3.8.4)+Apache(2.2.15)+Passenger on CentOS6.5
An agent run returns with

> Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve 
>       information from environment production source(s)
>       puppet://puppetmaster/plugins 
>       Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER:
>       Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Could not 
>       find declared class mediawiki at 
>       /etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/nodes.pp:10 on node wikitest

This is sequence of installing the module:

```
$>sudo puppet module generate my-mediawiki --environment production
$>sudo mv my-mediawiki mediawiki (just renaming the folder)
$sudo puppet module list
/etc/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
```

I have tried adding `$confdir/environments/production/modules` to `environment.conf` of the production environment and 
to the `basemodulepath` in `puppet.conf` as the first entry, but it doesn't seem to be looking there.
`$confdir/environments/production/modules/mediawiki/manifests/init.pp` has the empty class declaration. '$confdir/environments/production/nodes.pp` 
has the class statements in both nodes and both have the same error.

I've already tried:

1) removing the module and trying again, with all the puppet service stopped/started etc

2) there are no spelling or quotation mark errors

3) I've modified `metadata.json` in the `mediawiki` folder to be same as folder name just in case that mattered, but no luck.
4) Certificates are fine, communication is fine. I have another class defined as resource within the `nodes.pp` file and that runs fine.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Puppet will expect to find the definition of the `mediawiki` class in a file `mediawiki/manifests/init.pp` relative to one of the directories in the relevant module path.  Does this file exist?  Does it contain a definition of the wanted class?  Is the file readable by Puppet?  Are all the directories in the path to it readable and executable by Puppet?

Comment: Yes to all your questions, For good measure, I tried with ownership of the module directory given to puppet user and also added execcutable permission to the init.pp file. No change in the result at all.

Comment: with no further luck, i built a new fresh new vm, and followed all the steps as previously, and it works. did have to restart `httpd` before the puppet master picked up my changes to the `nodes.pp` manifest...

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, cause I've got nothing else to suggest.